# Run under the SQL Server agent service account option is disabled in for snapshot agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, user-accounts

I've created a publication in SQL Server 2005 (Also tested this in 2008). During the "Agent security" step, I selected "Run under the following Windows account" and entered an account.

Now when I view the "Agent Security" pane of my created publication the option "Run under the SQL Server Agent service account" is disabled.

Why is it not possible to select this option once the publication has been created and how would I go about changing this publication to use the SQL Server agent account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change this, identify the Snapshot Agent job under SQL Server Agent -> Jobs.  Then right-click on the job -> Properties -> Steps -> Run agent job step -> Edit.  Set the *Run as:* drop-down to **SQL Server Agent Service Account**.

Comment: this was done on publication, how to change the account on subscription?